# How to extract the max and min of a column with group by to a nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to extract the min and max of a column grouped by another such as this:

```
first_dict = dict(df_test.groupby('country')['population'].max())
second_dict = dict(df_test.groupby('country')['population'].min())
```

**Desired output:**

```
all_dict = 
{'Germany': {Max: 83, Min: 10}}, {'France': {Max: 63, Min: 12}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dict comprehension.

For example, starting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'France', 'France', 'France'], 'population':[10, 20, 83, 12, 15, 63]})

   country  population
0  Germany          10
1  Germany          20
2  Germany          83
3   France          12
4   France          15
5   France          63
```

Then:

```
d = {g[1]['country'].values[0]: {'max': g[1]['population'].max(), 'min': g[1]['population'].min()} for g in df.groupby('country')}

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'France': {'max': 63, 'min': 12}, 'Germany': {'max': 83, 'min': 10}}
```